# error when do Meteor add Angular-templates

Tags: angularjs, templates, meteor

I try to build the first app following the tutorial "Creating your first app". Removing blaze-html-templates is fine, but when try to do "meteor add angular-templates", errors happened, which are shown as below. With this error I can't go any further with this tutorial. I am a newbie of Meteor Angular user. Anybody knows why I got this error? I tried searching everywhere but no clues. I am using Windows 10 OS.

Many thanks.

> E:\meteor learning\simple-todos>meteor add angular-templates
>   C:\Users\XXXXX'S
>   PC\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.3_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
>         throw error;
>         ^
>
> Error: No metadata files found for isopack at: /C/Users/xxxxx'S
>   PC/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages/angular-templates/1.0.9
>       at [object Object]._.extend.*loadUnibuildsFromPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:900:13)
>       at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:521:21
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each._.forEach (C:\Users\GUILONG'S PC\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.3_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
>       at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:520:13
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
>       at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:515:22
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
>       at Object.download (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:427:20)
>       at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:600:22
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
>       at [object Object].*.extend.downloadPackagesMissingFromMap (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:597:20)
>       at C:\tools\project-context.js:808:25
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
>       at C:\tools\project-context.js:807:20
>       at C:\tools\packaging\catalog\catalog.js:100:5
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
>       at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
>       at Object.catalog.runAndRetryWithRefreshIfHelpful (C:\tools\packaging\catalog\catalog.js:99:31)
>       at ProjectContext.*downloadMissingPackages (C:\tools\project-context.js:806:13)
>       at C:\tools\project-context.js:283:9
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
>       at ProjectContext._.extend.*completeStagesThrough (C:\tools\project-context.js:273:18)
>       at C:\tools\project-context.js:265:12
>       at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
>       at ProjectContext.*.extend.prepareProjectForBuild (C:\tools\project-context.js:264:13)
>       at C:\tools\cli\commands-packages.js:2071:20
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
>       at [object Object].*.extend.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>       at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
>       at Command.func (C:\tools\cli\commands-packages.js:2070:27)
>       at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1483:23

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, try to remove manually /C/Users/xxxxx'SPC/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages/angular-templates directory. You might use **[rim raf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf)** node module for that. And after run `meteor update` it will reinstall angular-templates dependency again. That should help.